# How get the max of 9 last values in table of Power bi

Tags: function, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'll wish have the last 5 values in table Power BI ans this for each date + hour.
But my table have duplicate dates with different hours and I try a lot of dax function without any success. For example, this is a part of my dates in my table :
[Screen_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7BYM.png)

I'll hope get this result in each rows
[Example of result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgVl7.png)

[My data with my column name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F6Zr.png)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Remove the duplicates using the Query Editor

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column with the following DAX expression:

```
Max5 = 
var dt = Sheet1[Date]
var allbelow = FILTER(Sheet1, dt >= Sheet1[Date] )
return CALCULATE(MAX(Sheet1[High]), TOPN(5, allbelow , Sheet1[Date]))
```

What this does: For each row, we get the date. Then we get all rows
below this date. Last step is to get the max of the top5 rows with
the hightest dattime.

ps: Sheet1 you will need to replace with the name of your table